# ng-repeat not copying correctly over

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have `ng-repeat` working within a different template, however, I can not get my `album.html` template to display content.  Here is what I have.

**app.js**

```
...
            .state('album', {
                url: '/album',
                controller: 'AlbumCtrl as album',
                templateUrl: '/templates/album.html'
            })
...
```

**AlbumCtrl.js**

```
(function() {

  function AlbumCtrl() {
    this.albumData = angular.copy(albumPicasso);
  };

  angular
    .module('blocJams')
    .controller('AlbumCtrl', AlbumCtrl);

})();
```

**fixture.js** (where my object I want to copy lives)

```
var albumPicasso = {
    title: 'The Colors',
    artist: 'Pablo Picasso',
    label: 'Cubism',
    year: '1881',
    albumArtUrl: 'assets/images/album_covers/01.png',
    songs: [
        { title: 'Blue', duration: 161.71, audioUrl: 'assets/music/bloc_jams_music/blue' },
        { title: 'Green', duration: 103.96, audioUrl: 'assets/music/bloc_jams_music/green' },
        { title: 'Red', duration: 268.45, audioUrl: 'assets/music/bloc_jams_music/red' },
        { title: 'Pink', duration: 153.14, audioUrl: 'assets/music/bloc_jams_music/pink' },
        { title: 'Magenta', duration: 374.22, audioUrl: 'assets/music/bloc_jams_music/magenta' }
    ]
};
```

**albumt.html** (here is my template with `ng-repeat`)

```
<main class="album-view container narrow">
    <section class="clearfix">
        <div class="column half">
            <img src="/assets/images/album_covers/01.png" class="album-cover-art">
        </div>
        <div class="album-view-details column half">
            <h2 class="album-view-title">The Colors</h2>
            <h3 class="album-view-artist">Pablo Picasso</h3>
            <h5 class="album-view-release-info">1909 Spanish Records</h5>
        </div>
    </section>
    <table class="album-view-song-list">
        <tr class="album-view-song-item" ng-repeat="album in album.albumData" ng-mouseover="hovered = true" ng-mouseleave="hovered = false">
            <td class="song-item-number">
              <span ng-show="!playing && !hovered"></span>
              <a class="album-song-button" ng-show="!playing && hovered"><span class="ion-play"></span></a>
              <a class="album-song-button" ng-show="playing"><span class="ion-paused"></span></a>
            </td>
            <td class="song-item-title">{{ album.songs.title }}</td>
            <td class="song-item-duration">{{ album.songs.duration }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</main>

<ng-include src="'/templates/player_bar.html'"></ng-include>
```

`{{ album.songs.title }}` and `{{ album.songs.duration }}` isn't displaying any content nor am I receiving any errors.  I personally believe I am not copying my object through my controller correctly?  Further, how can I see my input of said object through my controller to test whether my object `albumPicasso` was copied correctly?

**For Reference**

This controller (`CollectionCtrl.js`) is working correctly and mirrors what I want to do besides the `for` loop.

```
(function() {

  function CollectionCtrl() {
    this.albums = [];
    for (var i=0; i < 12; i++) {
      this.albums.push(angular.copy(albumPicasso));
    }
  }


  angular
    .module('blocJams')
    .controller('CollectionCtrl', CollectionCtrl);
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`album in album.albumData`
May be you want to not override `album` variable name?

Controller alias is just variable in scope. You are overwriting it.

It looks like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < album.albumData.length; i++) {
  album = album.albumData[i]; // <-- We brake all things here
}
```

Just rename `album` in `ngRepeat` to something like `item`:

`ng-repeat="item in album.albumData"`

---

Also, you want iterate a `songs` array, not an object:

`ng-repeat="song in album.albumData.songs"`

and

`{{song.title}}`

Comment: agreed.  just replaced `album` in `ngRepeat` with `songItem` instead.  Still isn't displaying my content.  (ie `{{songItem.songs.title}}`)

Comment: See you something with `{{songItem}}`? I think your `songs` is an array and should have an index: `{{songItem.songs[0].title}}`

Comment: `songs` within object "albumPicasso" is an array and ideally what I am trying to iterate through and retrieve.  `{{songItem.songs[0].title}}` obviously is rendering an error, however, I think I need to use this idea within `AlbumCtrl.js`?

Comment: I write addition to an answer: just iterate your songs: `song in abum.albumData.songs`

Answer (score 0):

`albumPicasso` doesn't seem to be a global variable so it seems it's not accessible from `AlbumCtrl.js`. Try setting `this.albumData` to some dummy data.

I would personally create an angular service that provides the album data and inject it in the controller.

Comment: I have a `CollectionCtrl.js` that copies the object via `angular.copy(albumPicasso)` and renders it just fine.  `<script src="/scripts/fixture.js"></script>` is within my index and above all my template scripts too.  Should be global.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a service for this

```
(function() {
  var albumPicasso = {
    title: 'The Colors',
    artist: 'Pablo Picasso',
    label: 'Cubism',
    year: '1881',
    albumArtUrl: 'assets/images/album_covers/01.png',
    songs: [{
      title: 'Blue',
      duration: 161.71,
      audioUrl: 'assets/music/bloc_jams_music/blue'
    }, {
      title: 'Green',
      duration: 103.96,
      audioUrl: 'assets/music/bloc_jams_music/green'
    }, {
      title: 'Red',
      duration: 268.45,
      audioUrl: 'assets/music/bloc_jams_music/red'
    }, {
      title: 'Pink',
      duration: 153.14,
      audioUrl: 'assets/music/bloc_jams_music/pink'
    }, {
      title: 'Magenta',
      duration: 374.22,
      audioUrl: 'assets/music/bloc_jams_music/magenta'
    }]
  };

  function fixtureService() {
    this.getAlbumData = function(){
      return albumPicasso;
    };
  }

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .service('fixtureService', fixtureService);

})();
```

and this service can be injected into your controller

```
(function() {

  function AlbumController(fixtureService) {
    this.albumData = fixtureService.getAlbumData();
    console.log(this.albumData);
  }

  angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('AlbumController',['fixtureService', AlbumController]);

})();
```